# How can a command with arguments be fed to Bash?

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys

I need to type UTC timestamps very regularly (e.g. "2017-01-25T1422Z"), so I have it set to a shortkey in Ubuntu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>). Specifically, the custom shortkey is set to the following command:

```
bash /home/user/scripts/type_time_UTC.sh
```

The script `type_time_UTC.sh` contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

xvkbd -text $(date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H%MZ" --utc)
```

How should I edit the shortkey command so that I don't need the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the shortcut that you are trying to set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> is often used by other programs, so I'd recommend you use something else.

Second, on my system, when I run the command you specified, it outputs error warning, specifically this:

```
xvkbd: Mode_switch not available as a modifier
xvkbd: although ISO_Level3_Shift is used instead, AltGr may not work correctly
```

so we might want to get rid of that one using `2> /dev/null` redirection.

As for setting keyboard shortcut itself, it's sufficient to do

```
bash -c "xvkbd -text $(date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H%MZ" --utc) 2>/dev/null"
```

and set it to a key combination that won't interfere with apps. Personally, I'd use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super(Win key)</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> , which is unused, but the choice is up to you. I for example bound mine to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super(Win key)</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

[image]